# XCode 7 dyld: Symbol not found after setting ENABLE_BITCODE=NO

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, bitcode

I have installed Xcode 7 beta 3, and I am able to run my code on a simulator, but not on my device. I was no able to build and also received the warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
```

So I set ENABLE_BITCODE=NO and now the device builds, but it crashes with the errors:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TMdVSS5Index
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/75C6AF90-20D1-4CC7-B206-94C8FAD41DEF/BiggerCity.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/75C6AF90-20D1-4CC7-B206-94C8FAD41DEF/BiggerCity.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/75C6AF90-20D1-4CC7-B206-94C8FAD41DEF/BiggerCity.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
```

My Podfile is:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
pod 'PubNub', '3.7.10.8’
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error? It has only occurred since I installed Xcode 7. Xcode 6 runs just fine.

Comment: PubNub recently released a 4.0 version. Is there a reason you are requesting 3.7?

Comment: I haven't updated it quite yet. It is something I will be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What needed to happen was I needed to clean and delete derived data. After I did that I was able to run my application on my device.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you (rather `AlamoFire`) is using Swift, therefore you need to turn on *Embedded Content Contains Swift Code* in the target *Build Settings* and Xcode will include all the Swift `.dylib` files when building the app.

It's possible you are using the wrong version of the `AlamoFire` framework as using this particular versions means that `.dylib` files need to be bundled with the app and therefore you can only target iOS 8+.  I would look for a version implemented in Objective-C.

Comment: If you're suggesting an Objective C option wouldn't AFNetworking (the Obj-C cousin to Alamofire) be a better fit?